# best practices to import text into html

Tags: html, content-management-system, ms-word, adobe-indesign

What is the best practice for importing text into html from a multipage InDesign document, from designer to non-designer. Document designed on a mac going to CMS on PC - hand off the InDesign File or strip text into word file? Supplying all images and pdf as go-by?

Answer (score 1):

More people are likely to be able to open a PDF than InDesign, especially with font considerations. I prefer to get work in PDF format. I can easily extract the text and I can pull the document into PhotoShop to slice it up. You just have to make sure the quality/compression settings are right so it doesn't muck up the JPEGs too much.